# Exclude data with null values in crystal report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have this formula in crystal reports

```
Global NumberVar Array Z := [
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.1}) then 0 else tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.1}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.2}) then 0 else tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.2}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.3}) then 0 else tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.3}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.4}) then 0 else tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.4}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.5}) then 0 else tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.5}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.6}) then 0 else tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.6}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.7}) then 0 else tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.7}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.8}) then 0 else tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.8}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.9}) then 0 else tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.9}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.10}) then 0 else tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.10}) ];

Minimum (Z)
```

What I would want is when the data is null, It should be excluded in my report

For graphical example, The values would be like this:

```
1.1,1.2,1.9,1.5,1.88,0,0,0,0,0
```

where the `0` represents the null and the `1` represents the values.

I would like to get the minimum value, which would be `1.1` and not `0`. How should I do it?

Do take note that each number in the example is a different field in my crystal report which is so named as:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: What is the problem with this formula?

Comment: @Siva The problem is I get 0 instead of 1.1, where 0 is null and should have not been  included in the selection. I could not unselect the 0 since my data is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try 2 ways.

If you want to store null values then you can take 2 arrays one for storing only `0` that is null and another array to store other values.

If you don't need 0 to be stored then change formula this way:

```
Global NumberVar Array Z;

IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.1}) then 0 else Z:= tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.1}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.2}) then 0 else Z:= tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.2}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.3}) then 0 else Z:= tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.3}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.4}) then 0 else Z:= tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.4}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.5}) then 0 else Z:= tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.5}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.6}) then 0 else Z:= tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.6}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.7}) then 0 else Z:= tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.7}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.8}) then 0 else Z:= tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.8}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.9}) then 0 else Z:= tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.9}) , 
IF isnull({MIPIRReport;1.10}) then 0 else Z:= tonumber({MIPIRReport;1.10}) ;

Minimum (Z)
```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: but sir, with this formula, if `{MIPIRReport;1.10}` is null, then it will return 0. is there a way for nulls to be represented as **Blanks** but can still **add** it?

Comment: yes you can instead of 0 you can use `""` then it will add null